# Reading file that changes over time C++

Tags: c++, file, input, output

I am going to read a file in C++. The reading itself is happening in a while-loop, and is reading from one file.

When the function reads information from the file, it is going to push this information up some place in the system. The problem is that this file may change while the loop is ongoing.

How may I catch that new information in the file? I tried out `std::ifstream` reading and changing my file manually on my computer as the endless-loop (with a `sleep(2)` between each loop) was ongoing, but as expected -- nothing happend.

EDIT: the file will overwrite itself at each new entry of data to the file.

Help?

Running on virtual box Ubuntu Linux 12.04, if that may be useful info. And this is not homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution is something along the lines of what MichaelH
proposes: the writing process opens the file in append mode, and
always writes to the end.  The reading process does what
MichaelH suggests.

This works fine for small amounts of data in each run.  If the
processes are supposed to run a long time, and generate a lot of
data, the file will eventually become too big, since it will
contain all of the processed data as well.  In this case, the
solution is to use a directory, generating numbered files in it,
one file per data record.  The writing process will write each
data set to a new file (incrementing the number), and the
reading process will try to open the new file, and delete it
when it has finished.  This is considerably more complex than
the first suggestion, but will work even for processes
generating large amounts of data per second and running for
years.

EDIT:

Later comments by the OP say that the device is actually a FIFO.
In that case:

- you can't seek, so MichaelH's suggestion can't be used
  literally, but
- you don't need to seek, since data is automatically removed
  from the FIFO whenever it has been read, and
- depending on the size of the data, and how it is written, the
  writes may be atomic, so you don't have to worry about partial
  records, even if you happen to read exactly in the middle of
  a write.

With regards to the latter: make sure that both the read and
write buffers are large enough to contain a complete record, and
that the writer flushes after each record.  And make sure that
the records are smaller than the size needed to guarantee
atomicity.  (Historically, on the early Unix I know, this was
4096, but I would be surprised if it hasn't increased since
then.  Although... Under Posix, this is defined by `PIPE_BUF`,
which is only guaranteed to be at least 512, and is only 4096
under modern Linux.)

Comment: There is still the possibility of data loss on an I/O laden system.  The writer process may not have finished writing before the reader process reads, processes the partial file and  deletes it.

Comment: @suspectus If that is an issue, you can write to a temporary file, then rename it after closing.  Usually, in such cases, I'll finish up by writing a checksum; when reading, if the checksum isn't OK, I don't process the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just read the file, rename the file, open the renamed file. do the processing of data to your system, and at the end of the loop close the file. After a sleep, re-open the file at the top of the white loop, rename it and repeat.

That's the simplest way to approach the problem and saves having to write code to process dynamic changes to the file during the processing stage.

To be absolutely sure you don't get any corruption it's best to rename the file. This guarantees that any changes from another process do not affect the processing. It may not be necessary to do this - it depends on the processing and how the file is updated. But it's a safer approach. A move or rename operation is guaranteed to be atomic - so there should be no concurreny issues if using this approach.

Comment: Won't I miss data if there is a new input on the file during my sleep, and another new entry when I re-open then?

Comment: You will find it when you reopen the file

Comment: Even when the data on the file overwrite itself every time? Anyway, I am going to use this solution for now. And rather take the critic if my other team mates whine about it. Thanks for the replys :)

Comment: I've modified my answer - I think the safest approach is to rename the file (if possible) then process the renamed file. It's the type of issue that could bite you intermittently and could costs time and effort to fix.

Comment: If the data source reopens the file and writes the data at the start each time, and it writes twice between the moment you awake, you will lose data.

Comment: And, at least under Unix, renaming will have no effect on an open file.  If the writing is not atomic, you can rename, read and reach end of file before it finishes.  The proposed solution is incorrect.

Comment: James - you mean by writes twice - once before the rename, and once afterwards. I agree some locking is required to ensure writes prevail without loss.

Comment: @suspectus I mean that there are a number of scenarios which could cause a problem, depending on how the writing process writes.  (His edit says that the writing process will overwrite the data each time.  In which case, there is no solution if the writing process writes twice between the wake-up times of the reading process.)

Comment: The best solution would be if I could open the file once when the program starts, and close it when the program terminates. The data I am going to read is written to a device (that I am going to treat as a file) from a kernel module. I guess I should (perhaps) agree with my mate about time intervals which he outputs data to the file/device.

Comment: @suspectus The OP has since clarified the exact conditions.  In contradictory ways: on one hand, he says he overwrites, and on the other, he says he's using a fifo (which never overwrites).  So I don't know.  (If he's using a fifo, of course, seeking doesn't work.)

Answer (score 0):

To be more explicit, if you want tail-like behavior you'll want to:

1. Open the file, read in the data. Save the length. Close the file.
2. Wait for a bit.
3. Open the file again, attempt to seek to the last read position, read the remaining data, close.
4. rinse and repeat

Comment: This supposes that either the writing process keeps the file open, or it does something similar.  If the processes are long lived, you could easily end up with disk full.

Comment: What leads you to think the writing process does something similar?  It can close and open the file at-will as long as it doesn't claim exclusive read and write access at the same time when writing to the file.

Comment: Because it won't work if the writing process closes, then reopens the same file (overwriting the data).  This algorithm (which is the more or less standard way of handling the problem) supposes that the writing process always appends data to the file, and never overwrites.  If the processes are "short lived" (and in this context, "short" can mean a day or two,  depending on how much is written), and the writer always opens truncates when it opens, it's probably a very good solution.  If the processes run for a couple of years, and the writer writes a MB per second, it's not.

Comment: Ahh.  The poster has changed the conditions.  He didn't originally say that the new data would be an overwrite of the originally data.  As originally stated he implied that data would be appended.

Comment: Yes.  I don't know that he implied it, but he didn't say anything which would contradict it, and it is the more frequent situation.

Comment: Since we don't have gender-specific avatars, would you prefer we refer to you as "it?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) to watch file changes.
If you need simpler solution - read file attributes ( with stat(), and check last_write_time of a file ).

However you still may miss some file modification, while you'll be opening and rereading file. So if you have control over the application which writes to a file, i'd recommend you using something else to communicate between these processes, pipes for example.

Comment: Well, this is not a file, but a device that is written to by a kernel module. I am just supposed to treat it like a file.

Comment: @matkapluku What sort of device.  Devices behave quite differently from files.  For things like fifo's, for example, you should keep the file open (on both ends), since you cannot seek.  And reading removes the data, so you don't have to worry about disk full, even if the writer appends for years on end.

Comment: @JamesKanze: yes, we're going to use fifo.

Comment: @matkapluku In which case, the writer will almost certainly _not_ overwrite, but will append the information.  (And if the size of each write is small enough, the system will ensure that it is atomic, so the reader doesn't have to worry about partial records.)

Comment: Ok. I think we're solving it in the way that I am going to call a function `read`, located at the kernel module (not quite sure what my team mate - who is writing the driver - is planning atm). And I will receive a `char[]` from that function. Time will tell. I will update this Q with my solution when I get that far.